# Java security status 403

Tags: java, spring, security, jwt

I've configured simple security based on JWT tokens and roles. I've tested in in postman and every request have status 403 forbidden. I have no idea what is blocking my requests because even if i comment every filter and leave only permitAll it still says 403 every time.

Security config code:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${jwt.issuer}")
    private String jwtIssuer;

    @Bean
    public JWTVerifier jwtVerifier() {
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret);
        return JWT.require(algorithm)
                .withIssuer(jwtIssuer)
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/api/users/**").permitAll()
                        //.requestMatchers("/api/librarian/**").hasAnyRole("librarian", "programmer")
                        //.requestMatchers("/api/reader/**").hasAnyRole("reader", "programmer")
                        //.anyRequest().authenticated()

                )
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(Customizer.withDefaults());

        //http.addFilterBefore(new JWTFilter(jwtVerifier()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

JWT token filter code:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JWTFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private final JWTVerifier jwtVerifier;


    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = extractToken(request);

        if (token != null) {
            try {
                DecodedJWT jwt = jwtVerifier.verify(token);

                Authentication authentication = createAuthenticationFromToken(jwt);

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            } catch (JWTVerificationException e) {
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    private Authentication createAuthenticationFromToken(DecodedJWT jwt) {
        String username = jwt.getClaim("username").asString();
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = jwt.getClaim("roles")
                .asList(String.class)
                .stream()
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .toList();

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);
    }

    // Extract the JWT token from the request
    private String extractToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
         String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because in your method `extractToken` you extract the `token` but return `null`.

For future questions, please provide some JUnit test, or the request you sent via Postman. Additionally, spring-security DEBUG logs would be helpful as well.